# pywinauto makes the browsers lag while getting tabs url

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm, multiprocessing, pywinauto

I have this function that is responsible for retrieving browser active tab's url and it works like a charm. However, when I run this code even once, the browser lags, I have a function like this made for other browsers too, so when my code interacts with any browser, it lags. This functionality is very important for me so please suggest me an efficient way to resolve this lag issue.

```
import pywinauto

    def getChromeTabURL(self):
        try:
            desktop = pywinauto.Desktop(backend="uia")
            window = desktop.windows(title_re=f".*Chrome.*", control_type="Pane")[0]
            address_bar = window.descendants(title="Address and search bar", control_type="Edit")[0]
            url = address_bar.get_value()
            return url 
        except IndexError as ie:
            return None
```

I'm using threading and have also tried multiprocessing in python because I thought maybe that was the issue, but it didn't solve anything.